# MDT Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, windows-10, mdt

i am deploying a captured 64 bit version of Windows 10 Educational Version to Surface Pro 4's using MDT/AIK and WDS. The task sequence has been plagued with errors, i had a bitlocker error and am getting:

```
Error 5210 validate deployroot with recovery 
failed to run the action enable preboot input protectors
```

Even after turning off bitlocker completely i am getting this error. There is no more information to track down what this might be.

The OS installs, but then isnt doing any of the domain join stuff / post install stuff or using the custom settings.ini by the look of it.

the only thing i can think of is that something is either already locked (TPM?) or that when i used DISM to capture the image, the drive letters have changed and the bitlocker drive isnt being created properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is the keyboard attached?

If not, attach the keyboard and try running your task sequence again.